# Storybook can not find NX shared component

Tags: webpack, storybook, nrwl-nx

our structure is like this

```
|--apps
   -storybook
   -mobileapp
   -webapp
|--libs
   -ui/src
     -components
     index.ts
```

and when we are trying to import some component from libs via `import { HeaderLevelOne } from '@ouravesome-app/ui'` we get this error:

```
99% done plugins webpack-hot-middlewarewebpack built preview f0a7fccef24e2be0d9e0 in 5676ms
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ouravesome-app/ui' in '/Users/myname/Documents/work/app/@ouravesome-app/ui/apps/storybook/src/typography'

...

 no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/myname/Documents/work/app-frontend/apps/storybook/node_modules/@ouravesome-app/ui doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/myname/Documents/work/app/app-frontend/apps/storybook/node_modules/@ouravesome-app/ui.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
...
```

in folder `typography` we had a story that we would like to present

```
...
import { HeaderLevelOne } from '@ouravesome-app/ui' 

storiesOf('Typography', module)

  .add('Subtitle', () => (
    <>
      <Text>SubtitleLevelOne</Text>
      <Text>SubtitleLevelTwo</Text>
      <HeaderLevelOne>TESt</HeaderLevelOne>
    </>
  ));

...
```

without that import, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I may be wrong, but can you try importing the NgModule the component is declared into in the `imports` array in your story file?

```
export default {
  title: 'MainComponent',
  component: MainComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [NgModuleContainingComponentToImportModule],
    })
  ],
} as Meta<MainComponent>;
```

Maybe this could work?